# Custom fields AFC in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made a one pager Wordpress page. I am using custom fields to make my page editable. I've created a template.php where I've put all my index.php code in. Everything is working well and I've been able to add image - and text fields. But the latest text field I've been trying to add, is not showing up on my template page when I put it near the end of the page. If I put it in another section on my page it shows up fine, but for some reason it wont get the text string from the custom field when I put it where I want it (as in, the text field is there but there is no text in it).

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
   <div class="section" id="section4">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
       <div class="container" id="container_message">
            <div class="header">Send me a message!</div> 
           <div class="subheader">Lets stay in touch</div>
                <div class="container" id="container_text">
                     <div class="image_handtext"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/H.png"/></div>
                     <div class="image_handtext"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/E.png"/></div>
                     <div class="image_handtext"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/j.png"/></div>

                       <div class="contact">
                   <h1><?php the_field('contact_text'); ?></h1>
                </div> 

                </div> 





            <!--<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><button class="button">Send me a message</button></a>--> 


        </div>




     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your missing the closing`</div>` for the `.contact` div. Have you tried passing the page id to `the_field()`?

Comment: I have solved it now.. I took your advice and also passed the page id to the_field() :) thanks